# Why does Yisro appear to have higher standards for judges than Moshe does?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, moshe-rabbeinu, parashas-yisro, beit-din-court

First Yisro says:

> וְאַתָּה תֶחֱזֶה מִכָּל הָעָם *(1)**אַנְשֵׁי חַיִל** (2)יִרְאֵי אֱ־לֹהִים (3)אַנְשֵׁי אֱמֶת (4)שֹׂנְאֵי בָצַע* וְשַׂמְתָּ עֲלֵהֶם

Then when He selected it says he got:

> וַיִּבְחַר מֹשֶׁה אַנְשֵׁי חַיִל מִכָּל יִשְׂרָאֵל

Why did Moshe lower qualifications from 4 to 1?

Comment: The Latin word *virtue*, for instance, comes from *vir*, meaning *male*, whose main characteristic is that of (physical) strength, which attribute latter came to encompass *moral* strength as well. Something similar is happening here to the Hebrew word `חַיִל`, whose basic meaning is that of *force, strength, or power*, and which can be understood either as *able bodied*, or *of unimpeachable character*, or both. In the latter two cases, the last three qualifications act as explanations, rather than additions, to the first or main concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Even Ezra says that the qualification of Anshei Chayil is the only one that can be verified. The other qualifications can be faked.

Comment: Moshe is a navi of the higest form,and  has an Aspaklaria Meirah and can ask Hashem, so I am not sure i understand that answer? I realize your just writing what he says but its a shavacha Teretz

Comment: Nevertheless, אין לדיין אלא מה שעיניו רואות. Moshe may know with Ruach Hakodesh (or rather, nevuah) who is and isn't worthy, but for purposes of Torah judgment he has to use his regular faculties like anyone else.

Comment: It is not Torah judgment though is a character test he is not serving on a din Torah here

Comment: Okay, but you still can't choose dayanim based on nevuah (or at least Ibn Ezra seems to be saying you can't).

Comment: Where does it say you can not use Nevuah in Fact to find out a Mitziyus you can use a Navi for example to find your Donkey here we are checking the qualifications a Meyiyus You can use a Navi for that purpouse.

Comment: Why do you assume prophecy provides all types of information?

Comment: As I said it provided the Location of a lost donkey then this would seem good enough too

Comment: But not necessarily where this affects Torah law or judgment; "the Torah is not in heaven." (Though maybe this wouldn't apply to Moshe Rabbeinu, who indeed several times asked Hashem for an answer to a halachic query and received it on the spot.)

Comment: @Alex: Yitro does tell Moshe to use his Ruach Hakodesh to choose the judges: http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9879/showrashi/true/jewish/Chapter-18.htm#v21 - perhaps, like you answer, Moshe elected not to (as you answered). Alternatively, perhaps even with Ruach Hakodesh he was unable to find them.

Answer (score 6):

Rashi states in Devarim Chapter 1, Verse 15:

> אנשים חכמים וידועים: אבל נבונים לא מצאתי. זו אחת משבע מדות שאמר יתרו למשה ולא מצא אלא שלש, אנשים צדיקים, חכמים וידועים:

According to Rashi, it would seem that Moshe was only able to find men with some of the traits and not all of them. Yisro was identifying the ideal candidate.  However, as we know in life, we don't always get the ideal candidate.

Comment: Thanks! Nice to find someone like Rashi addressing the difficulties you have.

Answer (score 2):

The **Nataeh Eisan** answers based on the Medrash that says that the Maan fell for Tzaddikim and the sick at their doors. An the non righteous had to go collect from afar. The sickly also received it at their door. so all Moshe had to do was check if he was an Ish Chayil meaning was he Healthy and the rest was observable based on where the maan fell so really they were all those things, but all he had to Pick was אַנְשֵׁי חַיִל.

Answer (score 2):

**Reb Shloime of Vilna** gives a different answer. He says that a convert can not be a Judge. Therefore all the people Moshe could Hire as Judges where born Jews that got out of Mitzrayim and hence righteous so the Prefab had all the other qualifications just  אַנְשֵׁי חַיִל which Rashi says means Rich so they would not need others money. Yisro did not know this halacha as he said מִכָּל הָעָם including the Erev Rav Hence he had four qualification and Moshe needed only one.

Answer (score 0):

The Shaare Aron In Devarim 1:15, brings from the Imrei Shefer, and the Emek Hanetziv, that the Sefer Hazikaron (sounds like a Rishon so I guess the Ritv"a?) says "Anshei Chayil" is a general term that includes the other three qualifications, and is not a separate qualification by itself.